# WPF ObservableCollection.Remove throws NullReferenceException

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, nullreferenceexception

The code that invokes the remove operation normally works, this is the first time that I've received the NullReferenceException. I'm trying to figure out whether I might be doing something wrong and whether the exception can be avoided to make the software more bullet proof.

The, relatively, big number of System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren calls seem a bit funky too.

Any help will be appreciated.

OS: 6.1.7600.0
.NET: 4.0.30319.225

Stack:

```
at System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.get_OldValue()
at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry_ newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp)
at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateContainerDependents(DependencyObject container, FrugalStructList`1_ exclusionContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1_ oldContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1_ newContainerDependents)
at System.Windows.StyleHelper.DoStyleInvalidations(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle)
at System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle, Style_ styleCache)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry_ newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty dp)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UpdateStyleProperty()
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.InvalidateTreeDependentProperties(TreeChangeInfo parentTreeState, Boolean isSelfInheritanceParent)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorChangedInternal(TreeChangeInfo parentTreeState)
at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnAncestorChanged(DependencyObject d, TreeChangeInfo info)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
at System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.StartWalk(DependencyObject startNode, Boolean skipStartNode)
at MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1.StartWalk(DependencyObject startNode, Boolean skipStartNode)
at System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateOnTreeChange(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyObject parent, Boolean isAddOperation)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
at System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem.OnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
at System.Windows.Media.Visual.FireOnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
at System.Windows.Media.Visual.RemoveVisualChild(Visual child)
at System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.DisconnectChild(Int32 index)
at System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.RemoveRange(Int32 index, Int32 count)
at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.RemoveRangeInternal(Int32 index, Int32 count)
at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.RemoveChildRange(GeneratorPosition position, Int32 itemCount, Int32 itemUICount)
at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.OnItemsRemove(ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.OnItemsChanged(Object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingPanel.OnItemsChangedInternal(Object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.OnItemsChanged(Object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.OnItemRemoved(Object item, Int32 itemIndex)
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.IWeakEventListener.ReceiveWeakEvent(Type managerType, Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEventToList(Object sender, EventArgs args, ListenerList list)
at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
at System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.System.Windows.IWeakEventListener.ReceiveWeakEvent(Type managerType, Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEventToList(Object sender, EventArgs args, ListenerList list)
at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
at System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChangedWithAdjustedIndex(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args, Int32 adjustedOldIndex, Int32 adjustedNewIndex)
at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.RemoveItem(Int32 index)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Remove(T item)
```

Comment: Could you please add some code which responsible for remove

Comment: Thanks Homam. There isn't much that i can publish other than MyCollection.Remove(item). Why do you think that it might make a difference? The entire stack is straight forward .NET in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in the stack trace a number of calls to OnPropertyChanged which indicates that the code is firing a number of PropertyChanged changes events.  If somewhere in your code you are holding a reference to one of the objects in your ObservableCollection then you can get a NullReferenceException if your code is trying to use that object.

Because you indicate this is infrequent makes me guess that the removed item is referenced based on a selected item in one the controls in your XAML (look at InvalidateOnTreeChange) in the stack trace.

I've included a code snippet here that show how a reference to a selected item might throw a NullReferenceException.  In my example I have a DataGrid that bindings to an ObservableCollection of Customer objects, and tracks its selected item.  When the code removes the selected customer from the ObservableCollection, the code fires a PropertyChanged event causing the DataGrid to refresh its selected item, which is now null.  In the example because I try to update a property on the selected item I get a NullReferenceException.  I am certain your code is more complex, but I hope this helps.

```
<!--  displays a list of customers and tracks the selected customer  -->
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" SelectedItem="{Binding Customer}">

<!--  command that removes an item from the collection -->
<Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Remove" Command="{Binding Path=RemovePerson}"/>    

// ItemsSource of customers  
private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers = Customer.GetSampleCustomerList();
public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
{
   get
   {
     return _customers;
   }
}

// selected customer from XAML SelectedItem
private Customer _customer = null;
public Customer Customer
{
  get { return _customer; }
  set
  {
    _customer = value;

    // if i don't check for null here removing a customer causes a NullReferenceException
    if ( _customer != null )
    {
      if (_customer.Factor != 0)
      {
        _customer.Factor = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        _customer.Factor = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}

// the button command ends up here to remove the selected item
public ICommand RemovePerson { get; set; }
private void OnRemovePerson(object obj)
{
  if ( _customers.Contains(_customer))
  {
    Customers.Remove(_customer);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some problem with visual part or databindings, not ObservableCollection.

Try removing all bindings, then slowly add them to pinpoint the problem and tell us what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. It turned out that I had `((DataGrid)sender).BeginEdit()` somewhere before the point where the error is thrown. That code fragment keeps reference to the collection values onto which the datagrid was bound. Hence, and attempt to alter one of the values with `BindingCollection[index] = newValue;` throw a NullReferenceException. I had to remove the begin_edit.